Highlight 3D plot minimum point
How can I display this plot in a different point of view, so I can highlight the minimum point?
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={1,2,3,4},
    ytick={1,2,3,4},
    ztick={0,50,100,150,200},
    xlabel={$r_{\mathrm{AB}}$\hspace{3px}(Å)},
    ylabel={$r_{\mathrm{BC}}$\hspace{3px}(Å)},
    zlabel={Energia $\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{kcal}}{\mathrm{mol}}\right)$}
]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,domain=1.0:5,y domain=1.0:5] {(32*(1-exp(-(x-2)))^2)+(32*(1-exp(-(y-2)))^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



@user320810 view={azimuth}{elevation}, by playing with that you'll get what you need. maybe view ={30}{30} ?

You need to play with the view={azimuth}{elevation}

\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\foreach \viewX in {0,30,60,90}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xtick={1,2,3,4},
    ytick={1,2,3,4},
    ztick={0,50,100,150,200},
    xlabel={$r_{\mathrm{AB}}$\hspace{3pt}(Å)},
    ylabel={$r_{\mathrm{BC}}$\hspace{3pt}(Å)},
    zlabel={Energia $\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{kcal}}{\mathrm{mol}}\right)$},
    view={\viewX}{30}, 
    title={view={\viewX},{30}},
]
\addplot3 [surf,shader=flat,draw=black,domain=1.0:5,y domain=1.0:5] {(32*(1-exp(-(x-2)))^2)+(32*(1-exp(-(y-2)))^2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}

